# Activate Microsoft Edge Window with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way to activate currently open Microsoft edge window with Excel VBA. There are many other windows open but there is only one instance of Microsoft edge open.

Tried AppActivate "Microsoft Edge" but it is not working.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate, to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76052662/changing-browser-from-internet-explorer-to-microsoft-edge-in-vba-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using Excel on Windows, you can try the following. I say "try" because a problem is that Edge, Chrome and other applications use the same "Chrome_WidgetWin_1" window class name (see [Why do chrome/visual studio code/edge all have the same classname "Chrome_WidgetWin_1"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69097239/11318818)) so this code relies on the combination of that window class name and the window caption ending with " Edge" (leading space char is intentional ... on my device, the Edge window caption ends with " - Microsoft? Edge" but I do not know if the question mark is always present). You could introduce more checks of the window caption if you get false positives eg if Chrome or other applications are activated instead of Edge.

The following code should be added by itself in a new standard Module. The code that wants to show the Edge window should just call `ActivateFirstEdgeWindow`.

The code is commented for an explanation but, in summary, it uses the Windows API `EnumWindows` function to enumerate through all windows looking for the window with the above noted class name and (partial) caption and, if found, sets the window to be the foreground window (and then stops enumerating further windows by not returning `True` from `CallbackFromEnumWindows`).

```
Option Explicit


#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function EnumWindows Lib "user32" (ByVal lpEnumFunc As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" _
            (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" _
            (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function EnumWindows Lib "user32" (ByVal lpEnumFunc As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" _
            (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" _
            (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
#End If

Const mlMAX_LEN As Long = 255


' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose: Activate the first 'Edge' window
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub ActivateFirstEdgeWindow()
    EnumWindows AddressOf CallbackFromEnumWindows, &H0
End Sub


' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose: Callback from EnumWindows
' Parameter hWnd (LongPtr): The handle to the next window in the sequence
' Parameter lParam (Long): The value passed in to the lParam parameter of the call to EnumWindows
' Returns (Long): True (or 1) if you want to continue receiving subsequent handles, False (or 0) to stop
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#If VBA7 Then
Function CallbackFromEnumWindows(ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
#Else
Function CallbackFromEnumWindows(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
#End If
    Debug.Print hWnd, "'" & GetWindowClassName(hWnd) & "'", "'" & GetWindowCaption(hWnd) & "'" 'TODO: delete me
    If StrComp(GetWindowClassName(hWnd), "Chrome_WidgetWin_1", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        If StrComp(Right$(GetWindowCaption(hWnd), 5), " Edge", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            SetForegroundWindow hWnd
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
    CallbackFromEnumWindows = True
End Function


' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose: Get the window caption for the given window handle
' Parameter hWnd (LongPtr): The window handle
' Returns (String): The caption name
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#If VBA7 Then
Private Function GetWindowCaption(hWnd As LongPtr) As String
#Else
Private Function GetWindowCaption(hWnd As Long) As String
#End If
    Dim lLen As Long
    GetWindowCaption = String$(mlMAX_LEN, Chr$(0))
    lLen = GetWindowText(hWnd, GetWindowCaption, mlMAX_LEN)
    GetWindowCaption = Left$(GetWindowCaption, lLen)
End Function


' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose: Get the window class name for the given window handle
' Parameter hWnd (LongPtr): The window handle
' Returns (String): The class name
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#If VBA7 Then
Private Function GetWindowClassName(hWnd As LongPtr) As String
#Else
Private Function GetWindowClassName(hWnd As Long) As String
#End If
    Dim lLen As Long
    GetWindowClassName = String$(mlMAX_LEN, Chr$(0))
    lLen = GetClassName(hWnd, GetWindowClassName, mlMAX_LEN)
    GetWindowClassName = Left$(GetWindowClassName, lLen)
End Function
```

I have left in one `Debug.Print` line for debug / test purposes to help show how the code works. This line can be deleted in your live/production code.

> **Per comment from OP, following is code updated to handle possible minimised state of the window.**

```
Option Explicit


#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function EnumWindows Lib "user32" (ByVal lpEnumFunc As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" _
            (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" _
            (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsIconic Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function EnumWindows Lib "user32" (ByVal lpEnumFunc As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" _
            (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" _
            (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function IsIconic Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
#End If

Const mlMAX_LEN As Long = 255


Private Enum nCmdShow
    SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
    SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3
End Enum


' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose: Activate the first 'Edge' window
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub ActivateFirstEdgeWindow()
    EnumWindows AddressOf CallbackFromEnumWindows, &H0
End Sub


' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose: Callback from EnumWindows
' Parameter hWnd (LongPtr): The handle to the next window in the sequence
' Parameter lParam (Long): The value passed in to the lParam parameter of the call to EnumWindows
' Returns (Long): True (or 1) if you want to continue receiving subsequent handles, False (or 0) to stop
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#If VBA7 Then
Function CallbackFromEnumWindows(ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
#Else
Function CallbackFromEnumWindows(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
#End If
    Debug.Print hwnd, "'" & GetWindowClassName(hwnd) & "'", "'" & GetWindowCaption(hwnd) & "'" 'TODO: delete me
    If StrComp(GetWindowClassName(hwnd), "Chrome_WidgetWin_1", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        If StrComp(Right$(GetWindowCaption(hwnd), 5), " Edge", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            If IsIconic(hwnd) Then
                ShowWindow hwnd, nCmdShow.SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED
            End If
            SetForegroundWindow hwnd
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
    CallbackFromEnumWindows = True
End Function


' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose: Get the window caption for the given window handle
' Parameter hWnd (LongPtr): The window handle
' Returns (String): The caption name
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#If VBA7 Then
Private Function GetWindowCaption(hwnd As LongPtr) As String
#Else
Private Function GetWindowCaption(hwnd As Long) As String
#End If
    Dim lLen As Long
    GetWindowCaption = String$(mlMAX_LEN, Chr$(0))
    lLen = GetWindowText(hwnd, GetWindowCaption, mlMAX_LEN)
    GetWindowCaption = Left$(GetWindowCaption, lLen)
End Function


' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose: Get the window class name for the given window handle
' Parameter hWnd (LongPtr): The window handle
' Returns (String): The class name
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#If VBA7 Then
Private Function GetWindowClassName(hwnd As LongPtr) As String
#Else
Private Function GetWindowClassName(hwnd As Long) As String
#End If
    Dim lLen As Long
    GetWindowClassName = String$(mlMAX_LEN, Chr$(0))
    lLen = GetClassName(hwnd, GetWindowClassName, mlMAX_LEN)
    GetWindowClassName = Left$(GetWindowClassName, lLen)
End Function
```

Changes are addition of `IsIconic` and `ShowWindow` Windows API functions and the `nCmdShow` Enum and code in `CallbackFromEnumWindows` updated to use them.

As it stands, if the Edge window is initially minimised then it will be maximised. If you would rather it were shown in a 'normal' state then change the use of `ShowWindow hwnd, nCmdShow.SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED` to `ShowWindow hwnd, nCmdShow.SW_SHOWNORMAL`.

Comment: Thank John....it's working....my observation-- the code brings forward the Edge window but if the window was minimized earlier then it doesn't bring it up....I tried adding ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized        in the calling Subprocedure but still the same.....but nevertheless it solves my problem and I can use it....Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks a lot John, now with your update it's bringing up minimized window also....great help!